# how to set iframe src to local file

Tags: iframe, google-chrome

I have an iframe in my HTML, where i would like to play mpeg/mpg files from local folder, but i can't load the video into the iframe. when i set src="http://www.google.com", it is displayed in the iframe, but if i try src="file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/jgabotero/Desktop/sample.jpg"
it doesn't display the image.

How can i set the src property of iframe to point to local files, specially the ones stored in IsolatedStorage?

Thank you in advance.

--
julie

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, except I'm trying to link to a text file on a server. When viewing the page in IE it looks fine, but chrome just shoes a white box.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can't display files in iframe form your computer using file:// its a security issue.

I also think you can't display images in iframe, ue an html or ohp page, to do this, so put the image in a html file, and link the iframe to this html file.

Comment: yes I thought the same thing, and even if it would be possible a html or php page to call up the image would be better

Comment: In Chrome, I can display a simple text file in an IFrame using src="http[...]", but not by using src="file[...]". In IE, however, both methods work just fine (no other browsers tested).