# Hide the actual local folder location in iframe src

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have the problem to show the html file on local drive in my aspx page on IE9. I have read the question at [how to set iframe src to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571007/how-to-set-iframe-src-to-local-file).

I can show the html file which is on the another drive on the server by the below code.

```
 <iframe src="\\servercomputer\G$\test6.html" title="test" />
```

I don't want people see my actual folder location. I tried to create the virtual directory under the website, but I got the "cannot find the page error" Would someone show me what I should do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You were going through the right route (virtual directory). What went wrong?

Comment: I don't get the downvote. The OP has a genuine question and has shown some kind of effort.

Comment: @MelanciaUK,I found that the file path is not correct. It returned c:\HTML\test.html'.   My folder is on s: driver
Webconfig:
<add key=”HtmlFolder" value ="/HTML/"/>  
The snap code in my aspx page
Dim fileName As String =”test.html”
Dim sLogServer As String = AppSettings("HtmlFolder")Dim severpath As String = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath & sLogServer).ToString
Dim text As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sLogServer & fileName)
 I also tried use 
String = Server.MapPath(sLogNotesServer).ToString
It got the same wrong path. What’s wrong and how I correct it? Thank.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have virtual directory that points at a network location - you will have to play with the "Connect As" and specify name/password for access:
[IIS Virtual Directory map to network drive (with drive letter) but fail to create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497131/iis-virtual-directory-map-to-network-drive-with-drive-letter-but-fail-to-creat)

Another way (possibly better) would be to have a proxy in C# that would download the file from another server